# Prestashop target specific store to disable class

Tags: javascript, html, css, prestashop, multistore

I got a multistore webshop in Prestashop the problem is that the revolution slider I use targets both webshops for changes although I select each shop seperately . I want to have a different slider for both webshops. So now if I add two sliders they appear on both shops. I want to disable the slider(s) I don't need based on the url from the shop. So shop1.com shows slider1 but not slider2 and shop2.com shows slider2 but not slider1. Is it possible to disable the slider based on the class in javascript or css?

I know mozilla can use @ document url(url), but that doesn't work on other browsers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have revolution slider, you should configure it differently for each shop in the back office. You do this, by selecting the shop you want edit the module slides. Save. Change shop, and edit for another shop.

But you want to disable a slide using javascript/jquery, i think it's possible. You can use an onload function and window.location.href to get the url if contains one domain then just do $( "#slide_id_to_remove" ).remove();